# How to Add UIView between two row of UITableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

[image]I know the tableview header and footer but I want to add UIView between the row of tableview in objective-c. and uiview have three button also. 
but how can it possible. Anybody can help me..

Comment: Why you consider it as a UIView? You can take it as custom cell.

Comment: I have attach image which i want to implement, in this, facebook, twitter, instagram and www.bacar.com.tr show only in first row.

Comment: So, how can possible to show only in first row not in second row..

Comment: You can consider it UIView OK. Then add this view as a footer of tableview for section 0. Give number of section 2. then it will show only with first row.

Comment: OK, I am trying...Thanks.

Comment: I have done, but i face one problem

Comment: Oh, What is that?

Comment: I have design on storyboard and set 
height 360 for section one and 340 for section two, But when i run in iphone 6s plus, all data is streatched...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132873/discussion-between-hari-mohan-and-amanpreet).

Comment: Look, Did you create that view in xib file? Then simple load it.

Comment: i have create on mainstoryboard..

Comment: i know it occurs because i have design on iphone 5 and run in iphone 6s plus,
but how can it solve..

Comment: Best ways is create it in xib file then you easily run on each device.

Comment: If storyboard View works for you then try Constraints on View. But I recommend to use xib file for it that will very easy to manage in future too.

Comment: Actually i am using autoresizing..

Answer (score 2):

You can not add `UIView` in between two row or cell of `UITableView`. You need to customise your cells. And while filling data to your datasource of `UITableView` you need some kind of indications which you need to match in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method of `UITableView` and based on condition you need to show your data cell or custom `UIView` which is already in your custom cell.

Answer (score 1):

Every `UITableViewCell` is a child of `UIView` class.
So in effect all your cells are UIViews which you can customize in any way you want.

So what you want to do is use custom cell. Create a model class for it, customize it as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose I have a UIView and I am creating its object in Controller class in which I have TableView:

```
 var obj_ProfileView : UserProfileView!
```

In ViewDidLoad Method:

```
self.obj_ProfileView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("UserProfileView", owner: self, options: nil)![0] as! UserProfileView
```

Then In TableViewFooter Method:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat
    {
        if section == 0
        {
            //Do as per your requirements
            return 184.0
        }
        else
        {
            //Do as per your requirements
            return 45.0
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView?
    {
        if section == 0
        {
            return obj_ProfileView
        }
        else{
            return nil
        }
    }
```